# How to fix Eclipse error: 'Path must include project and resource name'?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My Wind River Workbench project reports error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /LedaAP

at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2068)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFolder(Container.java:202)
at com.windriver.pb.core.build.model.WRTgtCentricBuildImpl.refreshMakeFileFolder(WRTgtCentricBuildImpl.java:539)
at com.windriver.pb.core.build.model.WRTgtCentricBuildImpl.generateMakefiles(WRTgtCentricBuildImpl.java:532)
at com.windriver.pb.core.build.model.WRBuild.generateMakefiles(WRBuild.java:408)
at com.windriver.pb.core.build.builder.WRBuilder.prepareToBuild(WRBuilder.java:40)
at com.windriver.pb.core.api.build.WRAbstractBuilder.build(WRAbstractBuilder.java:338)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:330)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:405)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:551)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:529)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:120)
at com.windriver.pb.ui.actions.build.WRBuildAction$4.doRunBuild(WRBuildAction.java:454)
at com.windriver.pb.core.api.build.WRBuildJob.run(WRBuildJob.java:66)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

WR Workbench uses Eclipse 4.6.3.v20170301 and Eclipse CDT.

Searching on the net it seems that this error can arise for various reasons. Any advice for how to diagnose this problem please?

I notice that the Resource Path is '/LedaAP'. Where would that be set?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Thanks but that .log file only shows the Java exception I mentioned above. I could paste the entire stack trace here but am not sure that would help.

Comment: Tje stack traces tells us what part of Eclipse is seeing the error so it is useful.

Comment: I've edited the original question and included the full stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace shows this is clearly a problem in some Wind River code - you should probably be talking to them.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks.